# P4SCC plugin error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

I am using P4SCC plugin with visual studio 2010. I have verified that it is installed correctly. Also verified that necessary MSSCCPRJ.SCC files are created (we have custom build script to create these files).

```
But whenever I open visual studio I get following error
Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
Zeroconf resolved 'ssl:perforce.XXXXX.com:1666' to ':7274601'.
TCP connect to :7274601 failed.
connect: :7274601: WSAECONNREFUSED
```

Also it does not ask for password. I tried to set P4CONFIG but still it did not work.

Please let me know if anybody has faced similar issue.
Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: What does `p4 info -p $P4PORT` say?

Comment: The above command is wrong. But I check with P4 info, I found that "Server address: localhost:1667", which is wrong. How to set this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - try Perforce's new plugin for Visual Studio.  It should be more stable and perform better than P4SCC.  It also has a few ways for you to set your connection information.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use an SSL-enabled server, your P4SCC client must be at least at level 2012.1.

You could ask your administrator to configure a p4broker process which accepts non-SSL connections and forwards them to your SSL-enabled server. This broker would then work fine with your older client programs.